# Triggering Event in BASH with inotifywait

Tags: bash, inotifywait

I'm monitoring a log file (it's a PBX queue file, it's written to when a call comes in and it's the result of what happens to the call, whether the caller hangs up, etc)

Here's what I have:

```
while inotifywait -m -e close_write /var/log/asterisk/queue_log_test;
do
  if [ tail -n1 /var/log/asterisk/queue_log | grep EXITWITHTIMEOUT ];
    then
            php /usr/local/scripts/queue_monitor/pbx_queue_timeout.php
  elif [ tail -n1 /var/log/asterisk/queue_log | grep ABANDON ];
    then
            php /usr/local/scripts/queue_monitor/pbx_queue_abandon.php
  elif [ tail -n1 /var/log/asterisk/queue_log | grep COMPLETE ];
    then
            php /usr/local/scripts/queue_monitor/pbx_queue_complete.php
  else
    # Don't do anything unless we've found one of those
    :
  fi
done
```

Now, if I run the script, it successfully sets up the watches and detects the change/close (I've tried both MODIFY and CLOSE_WRITE, both work)

```
Setting up watches.
Watches established.
/var/log/asterisk/queue_log_test CLOSE_WRITE,CLOSE
```

But the event is never triggered (I have tested the PHP scripts outside of the inotify script and they execute splendidly)

If I run a tail by hand of the file that's being watched, it's successful and finds the phrase:

```
[root@pbx ...local/scripts/queue_monitor]: tail /var/log/asterisk/queue_log_test
ABANDON
[Load: 0.00] [Time: 19:04:43]
[root@pbx ...local/scripts/queue_monitor]:
```

What is it I'm missing here?

Comment: You're running inotifywait and watching `queue_log_test` but testing for changes in `queue_log`. Is there some reason these 2 files are different?

Comment: Hi Joe:
Sorry, that's a typo, both files existed. I created the test file because the actual queue_log file is written to by the PBX software, I didn't want to interfere with it. Either will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `-m` switch of `inotifywait`, which makes it run indefinitely:

```
   -m, --monitor
          Instead of exiting  after  receiving  a  single  event,  execute
          indefinitely.   The default behaviour is to exit after the first
          event occurs.
```

And the while loop is waiting for it to finish, so it can evaluate is exit code to decide if the loop should continue or not.

Comment: Ok, the reason I was using monitor was because I want it to run indefinitely. IE: If it finds the event, trigger and then continue monitoring the file for future events. Is there a better suited way to do that? Now that you say it it makes sense I didn't think of it that way

Comment: @TD46 simply remove the `-m` and it will run indefinitely, as you are inside a while loop and `inotifywait` returns true if it triggers an event

Comment: Alright let me pop onto that server and give it a whirl

Comment: So that seems to have worked. Problem being now it appears I have a syntax error in the elif statements.

`/var/log/asterisk/queue_log_test MODIFY
./freepbx_queue_monitor.sh: line 13: [: missing `]'
grep: ]: No such file or directory
./freepbx_queue_monitor.sh: line 16: [: missing `]'
grep: ]: No such file or directory
./freepbx_queue_monitor.sh: line 19: [: missing `]'
grep: ]: No such file or directory
Setting up watches.
Watches established.`

I placed the GREP queries in single quotes and ensured I had spaces before the brackets on both sides of the if/elif expression

Comment: You seem to be missing some closing brackets: `]`. Also `grep` is not finding requested files.

Comment: Ended up removing the brackets and resolving issue. Thanks for the help